# evaluate the numbers from the coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I need to solve this problem and I know the answer is -220 but I want to know how to find n and r in the coefficient of $x^3$ $y^9$ in the expansion of $(x-y)^{12}$.

I know how to do a problems with the expansion of (x+y). This is what I do to find n and r to use it on the formula of C(n,r). I use the formula of $x^{n-r}$ and $y^r$.

But how do you approach a problem with the expansions of (x-y) or (3x+y). What formula should I use to find n and r for C(n,r).

Comment: $(a+b)^n=\sum{n\choose r}a^{n-r}b^r$, so if $b=-y$, as in your $x^3y^9$ case the coefficient is just $(-1)^9{12\choose 3}=-220$.

Answer (score 1):

For an expression $(ax+by)^n$, the coefficient for the term $x^{n-r}y^r$ would be $a^{n-r}b^r{n\choose r}$.

In your example, $a=1, b=-1$ and ${n\choose r}=220$ so the solution is -220.